# How to display comment form error messages in the same page

Tags: comments, comment-form

I want to display comment form validation errors (as well as captcha error) on the comment form itself and not on a different page.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question have answered again, [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/comment-form-validation)

Also you can do the same with [JQuery and Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

You not to do anything other than install comment form JS validation plugin.
[Click here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/comment-form-js-validation/) and  download.

Comment: Used the jquery with some extra configuration and captcha adjustments

Answer (score 7):

I was facing same problem and was searching for solution i found the solution

Open your function.php file and past below code:

```
    function comment_validation_init() {
    if(is_single() && comments_open() ) { ?>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#commentform').validate({

    rules: {
      author: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },

      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },

      comment: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 20
      }
    },

    messages: {
      author: "Please fill the required field",
      email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
      comment: "Please fill the required field"
    },

    errorElement: "div",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      element.after(error);
    }

    });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'comment_validation_init');
```

For giving style:

```
.error  { padding: 10px 0 20px 0; color: #FF0000; }
input.error, textarea.error { color:#000000; }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation. What does your code exactly? And never use the wrong jQuery version, always enqueue the built-in jQuery.

Comment: It's important to point out that you're using the [validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) here