# Commentform - Hightlight invalid fields instead of prompting towards error page

Tags: comments, comment-form, comments-template

I have a huge problem. 
I used the comments.php from "EmptyCanvas".
Code of it can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/YHDy2q4a
However, it prompts me towards an error page when I do not fill out the fields as required when posting a comment.
I'd rather like a highlighting of fields, which I use with CF7 Forms. Code of it can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/uFgf07JB

I googled for it, and got redirected to another question which was not making things clear for me.

Thanks for any help,
Shawn

Comment: Bump, for the sake of a desperate man.

Comment: I have given the solution checkout
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131924/45948