# How to make custom comment fields required and message field not required

Tags: custom-field, customization, comments, validation

I have a comment form that has `name`, `email`, `brief`, `detailed` and `rating` fields.

The `name`, `email`, `brief` and `rating` need to be required, but the latter two are custom fields and I can only make them required through Javascript, but want to add proper WordPress/PHP validation to those fields.

The detailed field is actually the `comment_field` which is currently required, but I want to removed the required for this field, but I don't want to do it via the WordPress settings as I still want `name` and `email` to be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/comment-form-validation) that should answer yours. Basicly you want to use the `pre_comment_on_post` hook

```
    function custom_validate_comment() {
    //validate for brief and rating
if( empty( $_POST['brief']) || empty( $_POST['rating'])  )
        wp_die( __('Error: you must fill in both the rating and the brief') );
//make comment not required
if(empy($_POST['comment']){$_POST['comment'] == "empty_comment";}
}

add_action('pre_comment_on_post', 'custom_validate_comment');

function custom_change_comment( $commentdata ) {
    if( $commentdata['comment'] == 'empty_comment' )
        $commentdata['comment'] = '';
    return $commentdata;
}

add_filter('preprocess_comment', 'custom_change_comment');
```

That should at least get you on the right track

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who ends up here, the current way to do this is the `allow_empty_comment` filter

```
add_filter( 'allow_empty_comment', '__return_true' );
```

[Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/allow_empty_comment/)